# How to create a loop to generate increasing sample sizes in a simulation

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to create a simulation to calculate the confidence interval for a binomial proportion. So far I have a function that calculates the lower and upper bounds and I have generated and stored the type of data I want (in a matrix, I'm not sure about that).

How can I create a loop that generates samples with different sizes. I'd like to test how the formula performs when calculating the intervals with sample sizes n=10, 11, 12,... up to 100.

My code so far:

```
## functions that calculate lower and upper bounds
ll <- function(x, cl=0.95) { 
n <- length(x)
p.est <- mean(x)
z = abs(qnorm((1-cl)/2))
return((p.est)  - z*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/n))
}

ul <- function(x, cl=0.95) { 
n <- length(x)
p.est <- mean(x)
z = abs(qnorm((1-cl)/2))
return((p.est)  + z*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/n))
}

## my simulation for n=10 and 200 repetitions.

p <- 0.4
n <- 10
rep <- 200
dat <- rbinom(rep*n,1,p)
x <- matrix(dat, ncol=rep)
ll.res <- apply(x, 2, ll)
ul.res <- apply(x, 2, ul)
hits <- ll.res <= p & p <= ul.res
sum(hits==1)/rep
```

Comment: You code is little bit mess. Functions `ll` and `ul` looks the same to me. Whats `nrep` and ? When you aply cl function you don't specify the cl argument...

Comment: Sorry, there were 2 mistakes I just edited. Functions ll and ul are so similar because they calculate the upper and lower bound of an interval and they are just like that, only a +/- differs. I'm sure they could be optimized but I'm pretty new to R or coding in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which values do you want to compare between different sample sizes. But I guess wrapping your simulation in a for and using lists to store the results should work:

```
nrep=200
hits=list()
value=NULL
ll.res = list()
ul.res = list()
ns = c(10:100)

for(i in 1:length(ns)){
  p <- 0.4
  n <- ns[i]
  rep <- 200
  dat <- rbinom(rep*n,1,p)
  x <- matrix(dat, ncol=nrep)
  ll.res[[i]] <- apply(x, 2, ll)
  ul.res[[i]] <- apply(x, 2, ul,cl=0.95)
  hits[[i]] <- ll.res[[i]] <= p & p <= ul.res[[i]]
  value[i] = sum(hits[[i]]==1)/rep

}
```

Comment: I want to find out how many times the true value of p, in this case 0.4 is found in the simulated intervals. Thanks for your answer it was very helpful to get me started!